# Почему выводит ошибку AttributeError?

Tags: python, fastapi

Существует две версии кода.
В первом случае функции read_menus передается соединение с БД:

```
# router.py
@router.get("/", response_model=list[schemas.Menu])
def read_menus(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    menus = service.get_menus(db)
    if not menus:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=204, detail="No menu found")
    return menus

# service.py
def get_menus(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.Menu).all()
```

Во втором соединение с БД создается в функции get_menus:

```
# router.py
@router.get("/", response_model=list[schemas.Menu])
def read_menus():
    menus = service.get_menus()
    if not menus:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=204, detail="No menu found")
    return menus

# servise.py
def get_menus():
    db: Session = Depends(get_db)
    return db.query(models.Menu).all()
```

В первом случае все работает, а во втором выдает ошибку    `AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'`

Почему так происходит? В моем понимании Обе версии должны работать идентично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором случае ошибка возникает потому, что `Depends` - это декоратор, который используется для внедрения зависимостей, таких как соединение с базой данных, в функции-обработчики HTTP запросов. В данной конструкции `def get_menus(): db: Session = Depends(get_db)`, `Depends` не должен быть использован, так как над его использованием нет надобности и он вызывает ошибку.

В первом случае декоратор `Depends` правильно используется для внедрения зависимости `Session` в функцию `get_menus()` и это позволяет использовать метод `query()` для выполнения запросов к базе данных.

Поэтому, чтобы избежать ошибки, нужно либо использовать первый вариант, либо передать соединение явно в функцию `get_menus`, как показано ниже:

```
def get_menus(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.Menu).all()

def read_menus():
    db = get_db()
    menus = service.get_menus(db)
    if not menus:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=204, detail="No menu found")
return menus
```

Также стоит убедиться, что функция `get_db()` корректно возвращает соединение с базой данных.